# How can I redirect from anywhere in a document with PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my visitor to a different page assuming $good = true, but this is in the middle of the page so header('Location: http://www.website.com/page') won't work.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Oh gosh, now I feel really dumb ... What does that mean?

Comment: You should be doing all of your logical processing (this does not include render specific evaluations like a css class based upon some kind of flag) up front before you ever render anything so you should know the value of `$good` before you ever output anything to a browser.

Comment: Actually I meant [buffer your output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), although prodigitalson makes a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you haven't showed any html code yet,i.e. you are still processing your script so after that you will show the html, you can do this:

```
//... previous PHP code
if ($good){
require_once('myOtherPage.php');
exit;
}
```

}

You will be able to process any php code there and the variables in the current php file will still be accessible from 'myOtherpage.php'

Comment: could you please share your solution?

Comment: This solution is very good as it saves the user from making additional http requests thus saving time and resources. However you should also be careful. If the first php page has a different function then the second, and the user attempts to go back or examine their history you risk breaking their ability to go back to the php page that you included().

Comment: Alejandro, I re-wrote some code to make it work going above the html headers. @MikeBlouin Well, the "pages" I need to advance to are in an iFrame, so I kinda already screwed that up. Also, the function of the app is such that going through your history (assuming it was actual different pages), wouldn't really help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If your headers are already sent and you definitely cannot move this code higher up so that you can use headers (which is the cleanest way), then you can always echo out some Javascript:

```
<?php if ($good) echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://wherever.com"</script>' ?>
```

If you're doing this, its also good practice to place a button on the page that the user can click to be redirected:

```
<?php 
if ($good) {
    // Echo JS
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://wherever.com"</script>'

    // Let the user know
    echo 'Your browser is being redirected. If it has not already been redirected, <a href="http://wherever.com">click here</a>.'
}
?>
```